# How to stop previous item in viewpager holder with exoplayer with user scroll

Tags: android, firebase, android-viewpager, exoplayer

Exoplayer Inside Viewpager playing video after user scroll the pager this cause exoplayer to keep play the scrolled video and the current video which make the app buggy.

For past two days i searched entire google (google cannot be measured) although i tried, till last but no result was there

```
package com.gospel.gospelplex.reels.adapter;

    import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

    import static com.gospel.gospelplex.fragment.Short_Reels.reels;
    import static com.gospel.gospelplex.utils.Constants.EXTENTIONS;
    import static com.gospel.gospelplex.utils.Constants.SOFTWARE_EXTENTIONS;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.VideoView;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

    import com.dooo.android.R;
    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackException;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.RenderersFactory;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.ExoTrackSelection;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.MimeTypes;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
    import com.gospel.gospelplex.reels.model.VideosMod;
    import com.gospel.gospelplex.utils.MediaHelper;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class ReelsVideoAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<VideosMod, ReelsVideoAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        private final Context context;
        public static ExoPlayer exoPlayer;

        public ReelsVideoAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<VideosMod> options, Context context) {
            super(options);
            this.context = context;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull VideosMod model) {
            holder.getDatas(model);


        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_video_row, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        }


        class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            PlayerView playerView;
            TextView textView, desc;
            ProgressBar pbar;

            MediaSource mediaSource;
            RenderersFactory renderersFactory;
            String userAgent = "";

            DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector;
            Map<String, String> defaultRequestProperties = new HashMap<>();

            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                playerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_shorts);
                textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textVideoTitle);
                pbar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoProgressBar);
                desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textVideoDescription);

            }

            void getDatas(VideosMod obj) {
                userAgent = WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(context);
                DataSource.Factory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
                        .setUserAgent(userAgent)
                        .setKeepPostFor302Redirects(true)
                        .setAllowCrossProtocolRedirects(true)
                        .setConnectTimeoutMs(DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS)
                        .setReadTimeoutMs(DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS)
                        .setDefaultRequestProperties(defaultRequestProperties);
                DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSource.Factory(context, httpDataSourceFactory);

                String url = obj.getUrl();
                MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder()
                        .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MP4)
                        .setUri(url)
                        .build();
                MediaSource progressiveMediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                        .createMediaSource(mediaItem);
                initializePlayer(progressiveMediaSource);


                textView.setText(obj.getTitle());
                desc.setText(obj.getDesc());
            }

            private void initializePlayer(MediaSource progressiveMediaSource) {


                ExoTrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new
                        AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory();

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);

                trackSelector = new
                        DefaultTrackSelector(context, videoTrackSelectionFactory);

                renderersFactory = MediaHelper.buildRenderersFactory(context, sharedPreferences.getBoolean(EXTENTIONS, false)
                        , sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SOFTWARE_EXTENTIONS, false));
                exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
                        .setRenderersFactory(renderersFactory)
                        .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
                        .setSeekForwardIncrementMs(10000)
                        .setSeekBackIncrementMs(10000)
                        .build();

                playerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
                exoPlayer.setMediaSource(progressiveMediaSource);
                playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
                exoPlayer.prepare();
                exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                ImageView  volume =  playerView.findViewById(R.id.volume_mute);
                volume.setOnClickListener(v ->
                {
                    int currentvolume = (int) playerView.getPlayer().getVolume();
                    if (currentvolume == 1f) {
                        exoPlayer.setVolume(0f);
                    } else {
                        exoPlayer.setVolume(currentvolume);
                    }
                });

                exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
                exoPlayer.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPlayerError(PlaybackException error) {
                        Player.Listener.super.onPlayerError(error);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                        Player.Listener.super.onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady, playbackState);
                        if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
    //                        exoPlayer.prepare();
                        }
                    }

                });

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder) {
            super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);

            if (holder.playerView.getPlayer() != null) {
                holder.playerView.getPlayer().play();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder) {
            super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);

            if (holder.playerView.getPlayer() != null) {
                holder.playerView.onPause();

            }


        }


    }
```

problem is I cannot called ondestroy or onbackpressed or onuserleave method since i am using fragment
Simple words: how to stop old item or scrollitem in viewpager on scroll thats all
finally my exoplayer is inside the adapter so please help me on it if possible

**Error output right now : [https://res.cloudinary.com/djdle8unh/video/upload/v1687161287/video_2023-06-19_13-24-08_vumxy6.mp4][1]**

What i did

1. tried using kotlin method but still my app is based on java its quite difficult for me to get familier with new kotlin terms
2. researched exoplayer library issue they told people to ask in Q and A platform since its out of their theme.
3. Added pause method so video start with auto play pause a exclusive button is placed so user has to click to play video
4. mute button : video was by default got muted then user press unmute button to get audio

last two was good work through but still its not work for reels app so i came here.

I am ready to share futher codes...